# Over voltage protection to prevent appliances from burning

Tags: electrical, solar

I have recently installed a solar energy system at my home, I am currently looking for a protection device that could protect my inverter and other appliances from burning if an over voltage (let's say 440 V) spike occurs. And also when neutral becomes live in the case of a fault from the utility company.

Comment: Sounds look a shopping question

Comment: If the system was installed with listed devices and wired according to the National Electrical Cod then this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

A whole house surge protector installed at the panel will take care of surges. There is no real way for a neutral to become a line from the utility . neutral is bonded to ground at the service panel.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with solar systems and their inverters. You need not be concerned about protecting these inverters from an over-voltage condition.  The manufacturers are a whole lot more concerned about misapplied voltages to their unit than you are.  Their inherent protections are through and comprehensive.